# regular expression to express number range with ascending order

Tags: regex, numbers, range

I have to specify a pair of ports using format "number1-number2". Number1 and number2 both in range [0-65535]. But number2 is always larger than number1.

Is it possible to make a regular expression to expression the logic "number2 is always larger than number1".

Comment: If it is (which it really shouldn't be, as the language you've described isn't even context free), it's not worth it.  Just extract the two numbers using regex and convert them to integers and check that your inequality is true.

Comment: Oh... That is the last choice. I want to check whether it is possible to use regex, so it is neat...

Comment: What language are you using to do this?

Comment: It is java. Extracting numbers is my last choice.

Comment: Extracting numbers should be your first choice, because it's the best choice.  There's no way to do this in regular expressions alone.  You should use `"\\[(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\]"` to extract those two numbers and compare them.  The conversion from string to integer is miniscule in cost, and pales in comparison to how expensive any regex that might approach what you need would be.  We're talking massive polynomial exponents versus linear time.

Comment: Also, it will be most neat with numeral extraction.  Any regular expression that even approaches it will be enormous, ugly, unreadable, unmaintainable, and unreliable.  You don't want this headache for such an easy job.

Comment: I think I am persuaded. Thanks.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan sure the language is regular. It's finite ;)

Comment: @m.buettner  Haha, I guess you're right.  You could enumerate all the string combinations.

Comment: Hey Frankie, make your comment the answer!

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: Could you please write your comment in the answer box, so this question no longer shows up as "unanswered"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting numbers should be your first choice, because it's the best choice. There's no good way to do this in regular expressions alone. You should use

```
\\[(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\]
```

to extract those two numbers and compare them. The conversion from string to integer is miniscule in cost, and pales in comparison to how expensive any regex that might approach what you need would be. We're talking massive polynomial exponents versus linear time.